# Как все же авторизоваться через REST-запросы?

Tags: api, rest, тестирование, jmeter, fiddler

Всех приветствую. 
Сам вопрос в заголовке. 
Я записал трафик через Fiddler, затем записал это все дело в JMeter. Куча запросов отлично проходят, но те, что связаны с авторизацией - нет.
`401 Unauthorized`. Впервые делаю нечто подобное, как все-таки входить в систему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Буду рад любой наводке куда можно капнуть.
PS. Cookie Manager стоит

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу у вас в путях такие вещи как [`oauth2`](https://oauth.net/2/) и [`SAML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)

Скорее всего вам нужно добавить [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) и отправлять хэдер [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). Значение можете попробовать вытащить из Fiddler, если оно не динамическое - должно сработать. Если динамическое - вам нужно будет сэмулировать или OAuth или SAML авторизацию

Comment: Спасибо, я обязательно попробую